# No se me genera el pdf en mi proyecto laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf

Estoy intentando generar un pdf y cuando ejecuto la funcion me aparece la pantalla en blanco. estoy utilizando domPdf para esto

Este el codigo que tengo en mi controller:

```
public function pdf_facturas($id){


        $data = ['esto es una prueba'];

        $pdf = PDF::loadview('facturas.pdf_facturas', $data);
         $pdf->download('pdf_facturas.pdf');

        // view('facturas.pdf_facturas');
    }
```

En mi ruta tengo esto:

```
Route::get('pdf_facturas/{id}', 'FacturaController@pdf_facturas')->name('pdf_facturas');
```

Answer (score 1):

A tu codigo le esta faltando el `return`

```
public function pdf_facturas($id){

    $data = ['esto es una prueba'];

    $pdf = PDF::loadview('facturas.pdf_facturas', $data);

    return $pdf->download('pdf_facturas.pdf'); //<- return agregado
}
```

Saludos!